# tar/zip AND transfer to another server with limited space remaining

Tags: networking, tar

I have a folder which is 60Gigabytes in size on a server I need to destroy.  But, I only have 6G of space remaining on the server.

Besides the size of the folder, there are literally hundreds of thousands of small files in it.  So doing a simple `scp` would take forever.  I really want to `tar czf` the folder, but again, I don't have the space.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method that you can use (and which fulfills the "transfer to another server" part of the request):

```
tar cz sourcedir/ | ssh somewhere 'cat > dest.tar.gz'
```

Unlike scp, it's not doing individual operations, with separate round-trips, for every little file, so it will go just as fast as you can gzip (or just as fast as your network can transfer, if that's slower). Since the archive is getting written to a remote server, you don't have to worry about disk space. And since it *isn't* deleting as it goes, you can ^C it without being left with half of your files in their original locations and the other half in the tarball.

You can also get a live filesystem (instead of an archive) on the destination end just by changing to

```
tar cz sourcedir/ | ssh somewhere 'tar xC destdir/'
```

which operates a bit like `rsync` without the "sync". Add a `v` on the right side tar command to list files as they're received by the destination server.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for improving on my very simplistic self-answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution and wanted to share this: `--remove-files` is the way to achieve this.

So my command is this:

```
tar --remove-files -czf cpm006.tar.gz cpm006/
```

On a second terminal window entering `du -sh /home/cpm006` several times confirmed that the files are being deleted AS SOON AS they are added to the tar archive.

The obvious benefit to this is that you can do archives for the purpose of freeing disk space even if that space is limited.

Reference:
https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar